# AdMob Mediation - Facebook Audience Network "We haven't received a bid request" (Swift)

Tags: admob, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

So I'm trying to implement FAN using mediation via AdMobs. I have taken the necessary such as:

- Adding adapters
- Ensuring my app has been accepted/verified by Facebook
- Creating a mediation group

However, when looking at the business manager dashboard, it states there's an issue, the issue being:

> We haven't received a bid request

If I view the SDK instructions, it's shows my placement IDs, system user access token, both which I have added to AdMob, however, I'm also greeted with App ID. And for the app id, it states: `Add the app ID to your app and Google AdMob.` I'm sure this is the one thing, I haven't done, but looking at Google AdMobs, I can't find anywhere to add my app ID and furthermore, trying to set it in my application, there doesn't seem to be any way i.e. `FBAudienceNetwork.appID()`

So I'm a bit confused, my mediation report for AdMobs shows there have been requests as well with FaceBook, but now theres nothing to show.

Can anyone help me sort this issue?

Comment: any update? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @MostafaOnaizan I can't say for sure, as I just decided to just turn back to AdMob however have you looked at the app.txt file?

Comment: I have resolved the issue in my case I was always sending LDP for the FAN adapter, I resolved it by disabling limited data processing.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this code to your manifest, I'm not sure if this is the correct procedure though, replace fbapp_id with your own app id.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fbapp_id"/>
```

Comment: My apps an iOS/Swift app